# Undefined references to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at'

Tags: compiling, gcc, fortran

I use a  model is written Fortran90 under Ubuntu 14.04. The  gfortran 95 compiler (gfortran 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) and the gcc 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 is installed by Ubuntu Software Center. The installed gcc has an 4.9 empty folder in usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux/gnu as well.  The required netCDF libraries (netCDF C and Fortran netCDF) are installed as suggested in: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/. The netcdf is built as shared library.

The compiler options and LDFLAGS is set in the compiler_options.inc file by the following way:

```
ifeq ($(COMPILER), gfortran)
FPP= -x f95-cpp-input 
ifdef TESTING 
OPTS=-g -O0 -W -Wall -pedantic-errors -fbounds-check -fbacktrace \
-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -frange-check #-Werror 
else
OPTS=-O3 -pg -g
endif
endif

INCDF=-I$(NCPATH)/include 
LNCDF=-L$(NCPATH)/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf 
LDFLAGS=$(INCDF) $(LNCDF)
```

When I compile the model I get the following messages:

```
/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/test_cases_2d.f90:1446: undefined reference to  `_gfortran_runtime_error_at' 
/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/test_cases_2d.f90:1446: undefined reference to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at' 
/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/test_cases_2d.f90:1446: undefined reference to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at' 
/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/test_cases_2d.f90:1449: undefined reference to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at' 
../obj/test_cases_2d.o:/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/test_cases_2d.f90:1449: more   undefined references to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at' follow 
../obj/test_cases_2d.o: In function `__test_cases_2d_MOD_set_gate_thermo_profile':
```

It seems that gcc may not have found fortran libraries.

Could someone explain me what causes the error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Does your makefile specify more libraries elsewhere? otherwise it seems like you're not linking the gfortran library itself (`-lgfortran`).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Only compiler_option.inc file contains definition about LDFLAGS which contains netcdf libraries.  I do not know exactly how I should fix the linking to gfortran library. Does the following export command fix the matter? export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/

Comment: The compiler_options.inc file mixes up compile-time options (include paths) and link-time options (library paths and libraries), which confuses matters imho. However the simplest thing to try would be to add `-lgfortran` to the `LDFLAGS`. You should consider including the relevant portion of the makefile as well, i.e. the rule(s) for your executable target(s).

Comment: I add the -lgfortran to LDFLAGS by the following way: INCDF=-I$(NCPATH)/include
LNCDF=-L$(NCPATH)/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
LFOR=-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.a
LDFLAGS=$(LFOR) $(INCDF) $(LNCDF) but I got the same error messages. I tried again without /ligfortran.a but it neither solved the matter.

Comment: You're over-complicating things, I think. There should be no need to specify a **path** to the library, just literally add `-lgfortran` i.e. `LDFLAGS=$(INCDF) $(LNCDF) -lgfortran`

Comment: I run again the model with set up the `LDFLAGS=$(INCDF) $(LNCDF) -lgfortran` but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Well `_gfortran_runtime_error` **is** defined in `libgfortran` (you can verify using `nm -D`). You will need to look at the exact build command(s) from the relevant makefile(s) to figure out how to add it.